# Installing Percona XtraDB Cluster server

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, cluster, percona

I want to Install the Percona XtraDB Cluster server package  in `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS`

but I got this error:

```
sudo apt-get install percona-xtradb-cluster-57
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package percona-xtradb-cluster-57
```

Comment: Related: [Installing Percona/MySQL unattended on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9743828/55075).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percona software is third-party commercial software and is not present in the Ubuntu base repo. You need first to configure the Percona repo, [as explained in the documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-repo-config/apt-repo.html):

```
wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-cache search percona
```

If everything is successful, at this point you should see a list of Percona packages. Now you can install the Percona XtraDB Cluster:

```
sudo apt-get install percona-xtradb-cluster-57
```

Comment: I would add that this needs to be done as that package is proprietary/commercial, and cannot be found in the official repos.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you do not find something in packages.ubuntu.com,, apt alone without adding extra repos wont install it.